# How to simulate clicking the follow button on Pinterest using python + selenium

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, click

I just need to click this button, Xpath or CSS doesn't help to identify it, it doesn't work, are there other options?

Button image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWzJD.png

You can find this button on any Pinterest profile page.
For example here: https://pl.pinterest.com/pinterest/

My Code:

```
pint_subs_bt = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.RCK.Hsu.USg.adn.CCY.NTm.KhY.czT.F10.xD4.fZz.hUC.Il7.Jrn.hNT.BG7.hDj._O1.gjz.mQ8.FTD.L4E')
time.sleep(0.4)
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", pint_subs_bt)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
driver.get('https://pl.pinterest.com/pinterest/')
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.KO4 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1)').click()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).